# Securely keep the hash of the user when changing page in php

Tags: php, security, encryption

I have searched a lot but I can't find the answer to my question, I hope it is relevant :)
I use the **openssl_encrypt()** function to encrypt my data (stored in a database).
I use the **crypt()** function to hash my password.

I wanted to know how to keep the hashed password across the pages of my site, 
because I use it to encrypt/decrypt the data on my site, and I don't want to
 ask the user again for his password on each page....

I think I read that the session variables are not fully secure.

I would like to know if this is true and what alternative I can use in my case.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use sessions, which are secure. If they weren't every website would have a bad time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just generate a token each time the user logged in, update the database entry, and store this token in the session instead of the hashed password.

You can easily find the user by the token then.